# Macro code (for PowerPoint) that prompts the user to enter text, then does a find/replace?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

My Vb skills are beyond rusty so thank you very much in advance for the help. Can someone please share the code for a macro that will:

1) Prompt a user who opens an existing PPT to enter a value, let's say name. E.g. - "Please enter a name". Then the user clicks ok or enter.

2) Searches through every slide in the deck and where ever (literally) <*Insert Name here*> is found, it replaces that with the name the user entered.

Hopefully that makes sense. If someone can share that code with me, I would be extremely grateful! Many thanks again!

P.S. - in case it matters, I'm using MS office 2011 (version 14.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

Mightn't it be simpler to use Edit | Find | Replace and let PowerPoint do the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: Hi Steve. Yes, that would be simpler if the <Name> never changed, but that's not the case...so each time a change is made to the master deck the end users receiving the updated version would need to go and search to see what <Name> was changed to [e.g. - <Full Name>]. Whereas with the macro, the person updating <Name> to <Full Name> on each slide of the master could just quickly edit one line in the Marco and then redistribute the updated master deck.

Comment: Also, the macro would allow another option to "skin the cat" -- for those end users who are not very savvy with Powerpoint (yes, the still exist, lol) it would prevent them from having to look for the find/replace all functionality in the menu.

Comment: There's example code on my PPT FAQ site that'll get you started doing something to every shape/text box in a presentation:  http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00594_Do_something_to_--_every_shape_on_a_slide-_every_slide_in_a_presentation-_every_presentation_in_a_folder.htm  In most cases, you'd use the Replace function to do the replacement.  However, once you replace <Insert Name Here> with some other text once, the search string will no longer exist, so it'll no longer work.  There are ways around this that would involve tagging the original shape, but it gets tricky.

Comment: " for those end users who are not very savvy with Powerpoint it would prevent them from having to look for the find/replace all functionality in the menu."  But they'd still have to find YOUR macro.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks again Steve. So perhaps this is a naive question but...isn't there a way to have the marco to auto-play when the user 1st opens powerpoint, or no?

Comment: Assuming macros haven't been disabled, any code in Sub Auto_Open will run when an add-in loads (ie, when PPT opens).  PPT won't run code automatically when opening a presentation/template though.